# Need Advice... Website is flash only

Tags: html, flash

I currently have a website that is just one big flash file. It looks good and I am satisfied with it but I have been told that it may not ever rank very well in google and yahoo since it is only flash.

If you had this would you switch to html templates or keep as is. Any suggestions on how to improve my ranking if I do keep the flash site.

I am a novice so please excuse any ignorance on my part. I got the flash templates and html templates from host gator since they do host my site and little support comes with there services.

Thanks

Comment: Your site will never rank well in Google if the entire site is inside a single massive monolithic `.swf` on one page. It is possible to fix up Flash to work with SEO, but it's not trivial to do it right. As a novice, you're probably better switching to a HTML based template.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick with Flash and improve the ranking, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020849/developing-seo-friendly-flash-site (or other links below). If you want to write a real website, do that.

Either way, the choice is yours.

#### Recommended reading

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689510/how-to-make-flash-sites-search-engine-friendly
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358884/factoring-in-seo-on-a-flash-site
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510010/what-is-so-evil-about-a-flash-based-website
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368594/is-it-a-good-idea-to-build-a-web-user-interface-using-flash